# CodePipline Terrafrom || Action configuration for action 'Deploy' contains unknown configuration 'DeploymentGroup'

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codepipeline

I'm writing AWS CodePipeLine using Terraform. While defining stage for CodeDeploy as below, I get error :

> Action configuration for action 'Deploy' contains unknown configuration 'DeploymentGroup'

```
  stage {
    name = "Deploy"

    action {
      name            = "Deploy"
      category        = "Deploy"
      owner           = "AWS"
      provider        = "CodeDeploy"
      version         = "1"
      input_artifacts = ["SourceArtifact"]

      configuration = {
        ApplicationName = "windowsappdeployment"
        DeploymentGroup = "windowsapp"
      }

    }
  }
```

I checked documentation on Terraform but i didn't find anything related to configuration for CodeDeploy provider.

I think configuration parameter "DeploymentGroup" is not correct here.
What should I mention instead of DeploymentGroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should probably be `DeploymentGroupName` instead of "DeploymentGroup".

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/codepipeline links to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-pipeline-structure.html#action-requirements which mentions `ApplicationName` and `DeploymentGroupName` for `CodeDeploy`.